# Defining upright codimension math operator

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

How to write `$\text{codim}(Y)$` without `\text{codim}`?

Is there command like \dim that I can use to write codimension?

Comment: Never ever use `\text` for this. Use `\DeclareMathOperator{\codim} {codim} ` to define it.